# One of my pods is unusable, how can I fix it so it can be imported?

Tags: swift, xcode7

One of my pods (specifically TNImageSliderViewController) cannot be imported into my swift files. It also cannot be set as the class of a view in the storyboard. Oddly, TNImageSliderViewCell is available and has no issues.

Here's my podfile:

```
platform :ios, '9.3'
use_frameworks!
inhibit_all_warnings!
project '/Users/user/myproject/myproject.xcodeproj'
target 'myproject' do
  pod 'GooglePlaces'
  pod 'GooglePlacePicker'
  pod 'GoogleMaps'
  pod 'Google/Analytics'
  pod 'TTRangeSlider'
  pod 'TNImageSliderViewController'
end
```

Running pod update produces no errors or warnings

Here are pictures of what I'm talking about

[image: Pod files are there but there's an error bundle]

[image: Cell is available but Controller is not]
[image: Why]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Build the project after adding the pod